# Difference between PowerPoint.Chart.Axes and PowerPoint.Chart.Axis and how to use them?

Tags: charts, vsto, powerpoint

I am making a PowerPoint Add-in that makes different kind of charts. These charts are made by using `PowerPoint.Chart`

Upon exploring the `Chart` object I came across the method `Chart.Axes()` and the property `Chart.HasAxis`. PowerPoint interop provides two objects named `PowerPoint.Axes` and `PowerPoint.Axis` respectively.

The problem is `PowerPoint.Axis` object has some methods and properties like `MajorGirdlines`, `LogBase`, `MaximumScale` etc which I need to use in my Add-in but I can't find how to reference these objects to my chart's axes or axis property or what is the difference between `PowerPoint.Axis` and `PowerPoint.Axes`.

The [Axis Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.axis%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [Axes Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745246%28v=office.14%29.aspx) at MSDN doesn't help much either.

Comment: Generally, anything with a plural name (Axes) is a collection of objects with the matching singular name (Axis).  The collection will have properties like .Item (which you can use to reference a single member of the collection) or .Count (which will tell you how many members there are in the collection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Axis documentation you link to above is about Interop, the Axes Documentation is about VBA. The latter also has an Axis object, which has the properties and methods you want to apply. The documentation for that can be found from the link below the title

> Represents a collection of all the [Axis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744572%28v=office.14%29.aspx) objects in the specified
>   chart.

So, what you (probably) want is the documentation for the Axis object "[Axis Object (PowerPoint)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744572%28v=office.14%29.aspx)". In there you will find examples for the properties, e.g. the `MajorGridlines` example goes like this:

```
With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
   If .HasChart Then
        With .Chart.Axes(xlValue)
            If .HasMajorGridlines Then
                 ' Set the color to blue.
                .MajorGridlines.Border.ColorIndex = 5 
            End If
        End With
    End If
End With
```